# Push modal box ontocurrent page with reactjs

Tags: reactjs, dialog

I'm making various asynchronous http calls in my reactjs app. Errors from the server are streamlined and I would like to show an error dialog box in react regardless of the current page. I'm currently using the **alert** but I really would like a styled modal error box.

How do I detect the current page and inject the modal box and display it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create the dialog dynamically. It means that you will create and mount the Dialog component right after the error appears. You can refer this approach from ant.design team. https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/modal/confirm.tsx